# Does linking to universal static library (device/simulator) include x86 code in the produced binary for arm?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

I'm not familiar with the universal binary/library thing, and would like to clarify some questions in my mind.

I can build an universal static library that contains both device code (arm6/7) and simulator code (x86). Now It's not clear for me how the build process decides which code should be used from the universal library.

1. My understanding is that the xcode decides the architecture on which the target should be built by `-sdk` option. So does `-sdk` option not only specify which sdk to be used, but also to which ISA all the source code should be compiled?
2. If so, would it also automatically choose a corresponding part of the universal library, so if built for the simulator only x86 code is linked, and only arm code for the devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got no answers for ten days, so I think the question is too trivial to draw anyone's attention. Although I couldn't find any great underlying knowledge about universal libraries nor even an official document from anyone, but I just decided to make a simple dumb check on my binary size. I checked the size of binaries when I linked against an ordinary library and an universal library.

The results was the same. So I could conclude the link process does the right thing and close my stupid question =).

Comment: So you mean if I use an universal static library and when deployed to physical device, the x86 codes will be stripped out?

Comment: That's what I figured out back in March. Although I couldn't find an official document confirming this behavior, I think that's the most reasonable thing to do for universal static libraries. However, these days I'm not making universal libraries any more since I moved to Xcode 4. Including library projects into an application project seems a better approach, even though it has some disadvantages too.

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides the [lipo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/lipo.1.html) program for this purpose. XCode uses it to strip away unnecessary architectures when building your app bundle.